# Fill DataGridView by Multi values

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

i need to fill DataGridview by Multi selction
i'm trying to fill dataGridview by this Code and it's work but when i type
1,2,3 it's get the Right values but when i type 700 it's get 7 not 700
when i type 1,2,3,10 it gets 1,2,3
so how i can type 1,2,3,10,700 and fill datagridview with these data
thanks

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Text
Public Class Form1
    Public OLECON As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SCHEDULES_DB.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Admin@2014;")
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

        For Each fieldId As String In TextBox1.Text

            sb.Append("'").Append(fieldId).Append("',")
        Next

        Dim fieldList As String = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(","c)

        Dim SQLStr As String = "Select * from Tbl_Employee where EmpID in (" & fieldList & ") order by EmpID"

        dt.Clear()
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

        cmd.CommandText = SQLStr

        cmd.Connection = OLECON
        da.SelectCommand = cmd

        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting the text by every character, which is not what I think you are looking to do.  It looks like you are trying to put single quotes around each item in the comma-delimited string, so it should probably look something like this, where you split the contents of your string by the comma:

```
Dim items As New List(Of String)
For Each s As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(",")
  items.Add("'" & s & "'")
Next
Dim fieldList As String = String.Join(",", items.ToArray)
```

EmpID sounds and looks like numbers, in which case, the single quotes wouldn't be necessary.